# iptables rules for captive portal

Tags: ubuntu, сеть, iptables

Имеется wifi-роутер на вилане, не могу реализовать такой момент как завернуть весь трафик, чтобы он уходил на страницу авторизации, которая будет на сервере(он же и выступает в роли dhcp), вилан крутится на интерфейсе enp4s0, с другого интерфейса, который смотрит в сторону провайдера я смог открыть пропуск благодаря таким командам.

```
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" » /etc/sysctl.con
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Благодаря каким правилам iptables, можно завернуть трафик, чтобы не авторизированные пользователи, уходили страницу заглушку для получения доступа к wifi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дык, тут жеж важно как работает Ваша "страница заглушка". Допустим, как мне видится, самый простой способ это `ipset`. В теории это так: Предположим существует некие dhcp сервер выдающий адреса из диапазона 192.168.0.0/24 и web сервер "со страницей авторизации", которая, например при помощи php будет добавлять IP адрес юзера в ipset таблицу `ALLOW_TO_NAT`, тогда правила iptables будут примерно такими:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m set ! --match-set ALLOW_TO_NAT dst,src -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.2
-A POSTROUTING -m set --match-set ALLOW_TO_NAT -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Всё, чего нет в `ALLOW_TO_NAT` по портам 80 и 443 перенаправлять на web сервера, всё, что есть в этом сете - пускать в NAT.

Как видно, Вам нужно написать бэкэнд web сервера который будет отвечать за добавление адресов в табличку. На счёт удаления можно не беспокоиться, так как таблицы ipset могут использовать "время жизни записи". Однако должен заметить, что работать это будет лишь в теории, наверняка у Вас возникнут проблемы с `conntrack` и иже с ними. Вот заодно поэкспериментируете и расскажете нам, какие есть подводные камни, было бы интересно почитать :)

Comment: как доделаю до конца обязательно отпишу, что в итоге получилось)

Comment: Если Вам до сих пор интересно, могу рассказать как я запустил всю сеть wifi, проект уже как 2 месяца в работе.

Comment: Просто ответом оформите)